# wpf toggle datagridcell read-only

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with one column namely Qty ,where the user can enter qty only (editable) when the user press the Edit button on the form other wise its stand like read only field.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `CheckBox` or `ToggleButton` then you can do this with just a `Binding` without requiring any code behind:

```
<ToggleButton Name="EditButton" Content="Edit" />
...
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsChecked, 
            ElementName=EditButton}" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" />
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

If you use a class to display your items in the `DataGrid` (which is always a good idea), then there is a simple solution. You can just add an extra `bool` property to `Bind` to the `IsReadOnly` property and you can update the `bool` value each time the `Quantity` property is changed:

```
public string SerialNo
{
    get { return serialNo; } 
    set
    {
        serialNo = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SerialNo");
        // Update new property
        IsQtyReadOnly = serialNo == "The read only value";
    }
}

public bool IsQtyReadOnly // <<< New property
{
    get { return isQtyReadOnly; } 
    set { isQtyReadOnly= value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsQtyReadOnly"); }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<ToggleButton Name="EditButton" Content="Edit" />
...
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsQtyReadOnly}" 
            Binding="{Binding Qty}" />
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If you do it this way, the `IsQtyReadOnly` property will automatically update whenever the `SerialNo` property value changes.

Comment: in my requirement I have DataGridComboBox column namely SerialNo if the user  select one value from the combobox then the Qty field become readonly=true otherwise readonly=false

Answer (score 0):

You need an Event-Handler for that Button:

```
private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    QtyColumn.IsReadOnly = !QtyColumn.IsReadOnly;
}
```

Comment: No, it's the column with the name Qty.